# How to convert existing html to ajax without affecting the html dom level?

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, dom

First of all, I apologies to my poor English.

I am trying to update a html page. I want to reduce the content in the html file and import the content in run time through ajax (using jQuery).
The structure of the existing HTML is as the following

```
<div class="outermost">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <div class="inner">
     Content
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
     Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outermost">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <div class="inner">
// repeat and repeat
```

What I want to do is,
remove all `div.inner` and import the content into the place between `</h1>` and `</div>` at run time. 
i.e.

```
<div class="outermost">
  <h1>Heading</h1>

  // Content insert here

</div>
```

As large amount of html DOM level code are used in the jQuery file (e.g. `.parent()`/`.children()`), I do not want to insert the content by creating new `div`, which would affect the DOM level of the current HTML file, in order to get the content through AJAX.

One of the solution is updating `div.outermost` but I would not want to reload the heading. Are there any other way to achieve my goal? Thank you.

Comment: Have a read of the *Loading Page Fragments* section on the [`$.load()` function here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: I have read it already but it does not seems like providing any method to solve the problem in the situation that I said.

Answer (score 0):

You need `after()` ([docs here](http://api.jquery.com/after/))

```
//remove the div
$('div.inner').remove();
//get the data using ajax
$.ajax({
     url:getUrl,
     data: getData,
     dataType: 'html'
     success: function(html) {
          //put html AFTER h1
          $('div.ourtermost h1').after(html);
      }
});
```